# installing percona mysql on centos

Tags: linux, rpm, percona

From where will I get the **mysqldump** file from /usr/bin of percona mysql server (32 bit centos 5)? Is it available on the web without installing the software?

In other words I am collecting all mysqldump utilities built by percona for various flavors of Linux if they are really different than each other. I am starting with 32 bit centOS and I do already have 64 bit centos.

Is there an Image from Amazon web services with percona mysql already installed?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't that hard to install percona. Just read the following

http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/installation.html?id=percona-server:installation:from-repositories

It is really just installing the yum repo and running a few commands.. Yes there are some instances. Don't be lazy and search for them. Here's a few in us-east-1

```
 ami-61c16908 - centos 6 32bit
 ami-da778eb3 - centos 5.5 32bit
```